# JAXB Parsing - weird behavior

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I am receiving a valid XML from server. lets say

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="rootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="elementOne"/>
                <xs:element ref="elementTwo"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="elementOne" type="elementOneType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="elementOneType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="childOne" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="childOne" type="childOneType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="childOneType" mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="One" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Two" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Three" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="elementTwo" type="elementTwoType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="elementTwoType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="childTwo" type="childTwoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="childTwoType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="nestedChild" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="One" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Two" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Three" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="nestedChild" type="nestedChildType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="nestedChildType">
        <xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement>
    <elementOne>
        <childOne One="532" Two="938" Three="changed"/>
    </elementOne>
    <elementTwo>
        <childTwo One="532" Two="532" Three="68d53"/>
    </elementTwo>
</rootElement>
```

Could someone guide me what would be possible reason? I am unable to debugg from where should i start. 
the **nestedChild** is optional. so whenever JAXB parse the xml, it parse it in a way that if my xml doesn't have nestedChild, it shows 1 (empty object). if it has one nestedChild it shows 2, one valid and the other is empty. the transformation of valid child is okay, and obviously when the system try to convert empty object it throws exception ..

its jaxb v 1.3

Comment: You say you received a valid XML from server; did you actually validate it? The behavior smells like missing closing elements.

Comment: Could you please open your xml in a tool like xmlspy and validate. It does not look like a jaxb problem.

Comment: please provide the full xml file and the schema. if you cannot, try to build a minimal example that reproduces your problem. if you find your error on the way of building it, fine :-)

Comment: could you suggest how can i dump an XML. I tried using tcpmon but it isn't not showing my xml request/response. my app is running externally in weblogic server at port 8001 and i am debugging it in eclipse using remote debugging hooking at port 5001.

Comment: http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/results.jsp - so i validated my XML file against the given XSD and this stie tells its a **VALID XML**.

Comment: JAXB 1.3? That's prehistoric, are you absolutely sure?

Comment: lol, yes man. the "jwsdp-1.3" is the folder name. what can i say, can't move to latest version for some reasons